# How can I write formatted math formulae in matlab?

Tags: matlab

For example

[image]

Should I use static text or something else?
Thanks.

Comment: You aren't really giving much detail here, but I suspect you want to set the 'Interpreter' property of your text field to 'latex'

Comment: But Latex won't get you the blurry font!

Comment: I just want this formulae to be printed as it is on the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For plots `(title,` `label,` or `text)` and simple (polynomial) expressions, you can  directly use `LaTeX`-like notation and rely on the default [{tex}](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text_props.html) interpreter:

```
figure;
title('x^2+3x-10')
xlabel('x^2+3x-10')
text(0.5, 0.5, 'x^2+3x-10')
```

Same hold for images:

```
figure; 
imshow(imread('cameraman.tif'));
text(20, 20,'x^2+3x-10');
```

See also [TeX characters in MATLAB graphs.](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/adding-text-annotations-to-graphs.html#f0-28104)

For prettier, `LaTeX` math fonts, you can use the `LaTeX` interpreter (as the answer by @Shai and comment by @ioums), by passing a math environment around the tex-formatted string, i.e. `$...$`:

```
text(20, 20, '$x^2+3x-10$', 'Interpreter', 'latex')
```

[image]

Last, for printing an expression on the command prompt (for some reason), you can use symbolic expressions and [pretty](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/pretty.html) to resemble a typeset math format:

```
sym x;
>> pretty(x^2+3*x+10)

   2 
  x  + 3 x + 10
```

Answer (score 3):

use [`text`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html) command:

```
text( 0, 0, '$x^2 + 3x - 10$', 'Interpreter', 'latex' );
```